# Strange behaviour of the push

Tags: object, google-apps-script, push

Here is the simple script i cannot understand:

```
function test() {
  var o = {"groupName":"A"};
  var a = [];
  var b = [{"name":"1"}, {"name":"2"}];
  for (var i in b) {
    var name = b[i].name;
    o.itemName = name;
    a.push(o);
  }
  Logger.log (a);
}
```

I expect result to be

```
[
  {
    "groupName": "A",
    "itemName": {
      "name": "1"
    }
  },
  {
    "groupName": "A",
    "itemName": {
      "name": "2"
    }
  }
]
```

but it is not. It is

```
[
  {
    "groupName": "A",
    "itemName": {
      "name": "2"
    }
  },
  {
    "groupName": "A",
    "itemName": {
      "name": "2"
    }
  }
]
```

I want result include the same groupName for both iterations, but have different itemName

See the script here:

https://script.google.com/d/1VexsBJWZ1SBnb_4vnN1JA7a9KJkYzJ-hOcXwXvD2wa_GTXvdgt9xVOZb/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JavaScript, cloning objects is not as easy as it sounds. Object is a reference type not value type. Value types like numbers or strings will get copied, objects will be passed by reference, which means that your variable is just a pointer to the area in memory where the object is stored.

Assigning this variable to another variable will create a pointer to a pointer, and so on.

If you compare object variables  using '===' operator, it will return 'true' if both variables are pointing to the same object and 'false' if they represent different instances. Note that the result will be 'false' even if the objects have completely identical set of properties. What's being compared is reference.

In your example, push(o) won't copy the object - it will add pointer variables. The following code will return 'true', because you are storing two pointers to the object instead of two its copies.

```
Logger.log(a[0] === a[1]); //returns true
```

The code below copies the object.

```
  var array=[];

  for(var j in b) {

  var name = b[j].name;
  var newObj = {};
  newObj.itemName = name;

  for(var prop in o){

  newObj[prop] = o[prop];

  }

  array.push(newObj);


  }

  Logger.log(array);
  Logger.log(array[0] === array[1]); //will return false
```

Comment: I like for(var prop in o){

        newObj[prop] = o[prop];

    }
this answers to how i can copy the object easily and nicely

Answer (score 0):

When you are pushing object to array, JavaScript (Google Apps Script) do it by the reference, so next time you change `o` object, it will be changed everywhere in `a` array.

You can create `o` variable on every iteration to make it perform like expected:

```
function test() {
  var a = [];
  var b = [{"name":"1"}, {"name":"2"}];
  for (var i in b) {
    var name = b[i].name;
    var o = {"groupName":"A"};
    o.itemName = name;
    a.push(o);
  }
  Logger.log(a);
}
```